# Static method call not working in typescript

Tags: typescript

The static access in my following example does not modify the html document as expected and I don't understand why. I am new to typescript. Compilations were successful.

File Main.ts:

```
import { BabylonApplication } from './BabylonApplication';
BabylonApplication.test(); //<-- this static access yields no result
```

File BabylonApplication.ts:

```
import * as BABYLON from 'babylonjs';

export class BabylonApplication {
    public static test() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World.";
    }
    //..some out commented stuff where i need the BABYLON import
}
```

The index.html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Babylon Template</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.babylonjs.com/babylon.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.babylonjs.com/loaders/babylonjs.loaders.min.js"></script>

    <script src="built/SimpleJavaScriptClass.js"></script>
    <script src="built/BabylonApplication.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <p id="demo">test</p>

    <canvas id="renderCanvas"></canvas>

    <script src="built/Main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I noticed that when I write simple javascript classes with no export definition and import definition the static access is working.

For instance, the following plain javascript static method call is working

SimpleJavaScriptClass.ts:

```
class SimpleJavaScriptClass{

    static test() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World from javascript";
    }

}
```

Adjusted Main.ts:

```
//import { BabylonApplication } from './BabylonApplication';
//BabylonApplication.test();
SimpleJavaScriptClass.test();
```

So the simple javascript calls are fine. I have the suspicion that it has something to do with the import definition.
I used *npm install --save babylonjs* on the project (no, I don't confuse babylonjs with babel).

What am I doing wrong in typescript? Or what is wrong with the import?

Comment: If you add a "console.log" or a "document.write" to the static method. Does it work?

Comment: @TomášWróbel babylon and typescript are not similar technologies. You're probably confusing babylon with babel. Webpack actually uses babel even for compiling typescript, so it's definitely still a recommended tech. This however is about a rendering engine.

Comment: No, the console.log or document.write do not yield expected results. I am also not confusing babylonjs with babel.